# hidding iframe - stopping scripts in it while hidden

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, xhtml

I have in my page many many iframes which build this way:

```
<iframe style=".....">
    <html>
        .....
    </html>
</iframe>
```

what i want to do is to hide the iframe (maybe store it in js var) and stop the scripts inside it (flash playing , js function and such) and then active the iframe again. *what i mean here is that i want to remove the iframe from the page and then show it again.*

look , i have many many iframes inside my page. about ten or so. and it slows down the browser and make it laggy. i was thinking about hide the iframe that i don't need to make the browser faster

is it possible to do so? how? thank you in advance.

Comment: Stopping the scripts inside the iframe is going to be impossible. What is your use case for this, what are the iframes doing?

Comment: look , i have many many iframes inside my page. about ten or so. and it slows down the browser and make it laggy. i was thinking about hide the iframe i don't need touse in 1 click , and in another click whow the iframe and active it again.

Comment: it's not going to be possible to stop the iframes. Why do you have so many in the first place? What do they do?

Comment: @Pekka it some weird project.. what i need to do is hide the iframe , release some memory to not be laggy , and then when i need it back so i will show the iframe again.. could you help me please?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. All you can do is destroy the iframes, and reload them again. Would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to pause and hide them.  You can get rid of them and bring them back though.  This will just re-execute your scripts and restart your flash though.

```
<iframe id="iframe1" style=".....">
    <html>
        .....
    </html>
</iframe>
```

### JS

```
var html = window.frames['iframe1'].document.body.innerHTML;

//Remove
var html = window.frames['iframe1'].document.body.innerHTML = "";

//Add Back
var html = window.frames['iframe1'].document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: This is not going to work properly - especially with running scripts or flash movies. He could just as well destroy them and reload them

Comment: Hes not going to be able to pause anything, but he can reset it.